# Aggregate of string on anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I want to concat multiple string value into single string with comma separated,i tried using aggregate function but it shows cannot convert string to  how to fix this issue,

I tried below code

```
var res = (from e in WYNKContext.SurgeryAssigned.Where(x => x.CmpID == cmpid && x.IsCancelled == false)
                       select new
                       {
                           ID = e.SAID,
                           UIN = e.UIN,
                           SurgeryDate = e.SurgeryDate,
                           SurgeryID = e.SurgeryID,
                           Surgery = ((from st in WYNKContext.SurgeryTran.                         
                                       Where(x => x.SurgeryID ==  e.SurgeryID)
                                       select new
                                       {
                                             desc = icdmaster
                                                  .Where(x => x.ID == 
                                                   st.IcdSpecialityCode).Select(x => 
                                                   x.SpecialityDescription).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       }).ToList()).Aggregate((a, b) => a.desc + "," + b.desc),

                                     }).ToList();
```

I want Output like inside surgery property like = string1,string 2 ,etc....

without using aggregate i am getting as count in  Surgery Property

```
 var res = (from e in WYNKContext.SurgeryAssigned.Where(x => x.CmpID == cmpid && x.IsCancelled == false)
                           select new
                           {
                               ID = e.SAID,
                               UIN = e.UIN,
                               SurgeryDate = e.SurgeryDate,
                               SurgeryID = e.SurgeryID,
                               Surgery = (from st in WYNKContext.SurgeryTran.Where(x => x.SurgeryID == e.SurgeryID)
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          icd = icdmaster.Where(x => x.ID == st.IcdSpecialityCode).Select(x => x.SpecialityDescription).FirstOrDefault(),
                                       }).ToList(),

                                         }).ToList();
```

also tried string join :

```
   Surgery = string.Join(",", (from st in WYNKContext.SurgeryTran.Where(x => x.SurgeryID == e.SurgeryID)
                              select new
                              {
                                  icd = icdmaster.Where(x => x.ID == st.IcdSpecialityCode).Select(x => x.SpecialityDescription).FirstOrDefault(),
                              }).ToList()),
```

but in output  i am getting like this

```
Surgery ={ icd = CORNEA },{ icd = CATARACT/IOL }
```

can some one tell what i did wrong in string.join.....

Comment: Some reason string.Join is not sufficient? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string` class has a `static` method named [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1), which takes in a collection of items and a string to join them with, which should work for you here.

If I'm reading your code correctly, it would look something like this:

```
Surgery = string.Join(",", WYNKContext.SurgeryTran
    .Where(surgTran => surgTran.SurgeryID == e.SurgeryID)
    .Select(surgTran => icdmaster
        .Where(icd => icd.ID == surgTran.IcdSpecialityCode)
        .Select(icd => icd.SpecialityDescription)
        .FirstOrDefault())),
```

Comment: Thank bro! You code working like champ....can u tell what i did wrong in same string.join method i paste that above question area

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're selecting a `new` anonymous type with a property named `icd` that contains the value, instead of just selecting the value, so you end up joining a list of an anonymous type. If you really want to do that, you'd have to add another `select` to select the `icd` property, but that all seems rather pointless.